# How to use a value in a column as repetition count

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an update statement that needs to be run as many times as a value in another table. Here are what the tables look like

TABLE 1

| ROW_ID | CLOB_TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | text |
| 2 | text |

TABLE 2

| HOW_MANY_TIMES | ROW_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

Basically update statement should run on the first row, but how many times that it will runn will be dependent based on the first col from the second table. And i have ROW_ID col on the both tables to link them to prevent repetitions.

Should i convert my second table to the format below and run updates for each row? Or is there another way to do it maybe?

| COL1 | ROW_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |

I can do single updates for each row but i can't seem to do it in a loop(?) based on a counter from another table it seems.

Comment: I don't understand what is being updated. Does CLOB_TEXT contain UPDATE statement, or what? Anyway: why do you need TABLE2? Why don't you put HOW_MANY_TIMES column into TABLE1?

Comment: I'm sorry if i haven't made myself clear enough. First table has two cols. First one is the primary key and the second on contians CLOB_TEXT. Update statement searches the second col and removes a certain part of it. Lets say text includes a pattern different amount of times. And that amount is kept on the second table. Also editing the first table is not possible for me.

Comment: Hm; have a look at code I posted below (as an answer; can't put it into a comment which doesn't allow formatting) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're talking about?

```
begin
  for cur_2 in (select row_id, how_many_times from table2) loop
    for i in 1 ..cur_2.how_many_times loop
      update table1 set
        clob_text = replace(clob_text, 'A', 'B')
        where row_id = cur_2.row_id;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single `MERGE` statement (which for large data sets is going to be much more efficient than loops in PL/SQL):

```sql
MERGE INTO table_1 dst
USING (
  SELECT t1.ROWID AS rid,
         t2.ROW_ID,
         l.idx
  FROM   table_1 t1
         INNER JOIN table_2 t2
         ON (t1.ROW_ID = t2.ROW_ID)
         CROSS APPLY(
           SELECT LEVEL AS idx
           FROM   DUAL
           WHERE  LEVEL <= t2.how_many_times
           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t2.how_many_times
         ) l
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid AND src.idx = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET clob_text = src.idx
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (row_id, clob_text) VALUES (src.row_id, src.idx);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (ROW_ID, CLOB_TEXT) AS
SELECT 1, EMPTY_CLOB() || 'text' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, EMPTY_CLOB() || 'text' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 (HOW_MANY_TIMES, ROW_ID) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, `table_1` contains:

| ROW_ID | CLOB_TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EQ0n0Opa)